# Even if mapped, I can't reach the servlet

Tags: html, xml, tomcat, servlets

I'm developing a website with Tomcat. 
I'm using servlet for authenticate users before sending them to another page. 
At the start, everything worked fine, but now that I've moved some html page into different folder, I can't reach the servlet anymore. The pages I didn't move still work. 
One of the cases it's this: from a login form, I'm trying to call a servlet.

```
<form action="login" method="post">
        Email<br>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="email"><br><br>
        Password<br>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="password"><br><br>
        Stay logged in?
        <select name="cookie">
            <option>yes</option>
            <option>no</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <input class="invia" type="submit" value="Read!">
    </form>
```

Here the xml code

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Unfortunately I can't show images, but I'll describe you my organization: 
- the servlet **Login** in the *src* directory 
- the **form** is in the directory **D-Login** that is in the directory **web**

If I compile the form, it sends me to *http://localhost:8080/Servlet_war_exploded/Login/login* in the place of *http://localhost:8080/Servlet_war_exploded/login*

What isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet class must be in a package; the default package does not work.
And the value of your 'action' attribute in the form must be `"/context/login"`.

Comment: Thanks! Even if I didn't change the Login's directory, putting the action as `/Servlet_war_exploded/login` , it worked!
Why did you say to change directory?

Comment: Errrr, I was under the assumption that servlets can not reside in the default package (as was the case in earlier versions of the Servlet Specification).